# Google Forms regular expression

Tags: regex, google-forms

I am trying to make it so the users of the form can't enter an apostrophe. It causes issues with syncing to a Google Fusion Table. The problem I am trying to fix is if I say:

"Regular Expression" "Doesn't Contain" `'`

"Regular Expression" "Doesn't Contain" `[']`

"Regular Expression" "Doesn't Contain" `.*['].*`

They all work except if the user presses Enter for a new line and then they all fail and does not let the user submit.

I am guessing that this is simple to fix but I am just learning regex.

Comment: What is the element? Paragraph text? `Regular Expression` > `Doesn't Contain` > `'` [works for me](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1EQO_1WfiZYW7GHnBJa5n5yrUHytP59WLUB47LgA2-eI/viewform). Even if I type the apostrophe on any other line than the first one.

Comment: Do you want to let apostrophes on all BUT the first line?

Comment: I can't have an apostrophe at all. And yes, it is Paragraph text. This is with Regular Expression > Doesn't Contain > ' https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1OKSJP-ix46Glfx4k3wgRGuJuv9pv7JW1KUh9oR-VnnU/viewform Even if you just press enter it does not work.

Comment: I noticed that you are using the old google forms and it works. On the new forms, it does not work. I tested the exact same thing and that does work on the old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`Regular Expression` > `Matches` > `^[^']+$`

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^']+` - 1+ characters other than `'`
- `$` - end of string

See [sample form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1n5z2zjOW5ZU68dxlTlfiKmCHVJGiGeF_qpvbgO89Fyc/viewform?usp=form_confirm)

It seems to work with the new Google Forms, too.

Comment: Actually, I just tried again on the form you linked and it is no longer working for me there.

Comment: If you enter something and then press enter and click off of the text box it tells you "No apostrophes please".

Comment: I do not know what happened actually. I retried with a new form, and use a `Regex` > `Matches` with `^[^']+$` regex, and it seems working now.

Comment: Ok, I found a different way of doing it which seems to work better. The user can type them they just get removed after the form is submitted. This does seem to work but if the user does not have to worry about it that is better. Thanks.